# SQL Server date datatype becomes nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

After so many years, I have become part of a project that use SQL server. This time it's 2017. I found a very weird behavior when I create a table.

```
create table test (sampledate date)
```

If I run above and check the data type of column **sampledate**, it shows nvarchar instead of date. This causes an error in my application.

Btw I'm using DBVisualizer to check the data type, I believe this is not because of this tool.

Comment: what does `sp_help test` show as the datatype?

Comment: Why do you assume that the type is `nvarchar`? What did you try? Are you sure it's not your application or a badly written query that converts the `date` value to a string that can't be parsed by the client?

Comment: I suspect your tool [cannot handle date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#backward-compatibility-for-down-level-clients)

Comment: What do you mean "check the data type"? Have you brought this up with DBVisualizer support? Maybe they haven't updated their metadata enums since 2005...

Comment: On what grounds do you "believe this is not because of this tool."?

Comment: Okay thanks guys, my bad. I'm just relying on DBVisualizer UI because I don't have SSMS installed on my machine. using sp_help really shows the actual data type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this section of the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#backward-compatibility-for-down-level-clients). It explains that with down-level clients, the backward compatibility of the `date` data type is ensured by being converted to String/Varchar. So it may really comes from the DBVisualizer usage.
For your app, check the version of the client you use.